# pip installed packages not found in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I am working with venv in VS code on windows 10, and it kept throwing `ModuleNotFoundError`, even if I have already tried `py -m pip install <package name>`. The weirdest part was that `pip freeze` or `pip list` returns nothing.

If I navigate to the `env/Lib/site-packages` folder, I can see that the package folder is already there, so I am assuming the package has been installed.

I think it's worth noting that the above problem only happens after I activated the virtual environment, and `pip freeze` is still working normally when I am not in `venv`.

Some details: (can provide more if needed)

- windows 10
- VS code 1.59.0
- python 3.9.6 64-bit

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue!

Comment: I've tried many ways to solve it. However one of my computer working perfectly fine despite of another.

Answer (score 1):

The query is still unclear. Can you show the exact error msg thrown? i.e. message after `ModuleNotFoundError`.

**pip is a package installer and it is present by default when you create a new virtual environment**

if the error still persists, you can try this:

**First reason** to why `pip freeze` or `pip list` doesn't show anything is that you don't have any packages installed in your virtual environment. If it doesn't throw any other error messages, it means it working just fine and showing a null list. The packages may be installed outside the virtual env.

**Second reason** is that somehow your package installer *pip* is uninstalled from the virtual env. But in this case whenever you use any pip command it always throws an error something like `'pip' module not found.`

To resolve this (*second reason*)

- you can simply deactivate the virtual env and create a new one.
  `python -m venv new_env_name`.  Then install all your libraries at once using the **requirements.txt** file.
- **Or** you will have to download and install **pip** manually in your virtual env. Since I find it cumbersome, I prefer the previous workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `pip` command as in `pip freeze` is not the one bound to your `venv`. Similar to the install command, try `py -m pip freeze` and then check if the package is installed.

How do you run your python program? just using `python scripty.py`?
Try to check which `site-packages` your python is using:

`python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"`

Then check where your package is installed:
`py -m pip show <package-name>`

It should provide info regarding the package, including its location. Check that this is the same location as shown in the previous command.

If there are not the same locations, you are using python and pip that are not binded to each other

Comment: 1. `py -m pip freeze` is the same. Returns nothing. 2. yes, I am running as `python scripty.py`. That line of code returns of path of my venv folder. `py -m pip show <pkg>` returns the following error: `WARNING: Package(s) not found: <pkg>`

Comment: 1. You need to replace <pkg> woth the real package name, did you fo that? 2. Are you sure the installation is completed successfully? 3. Why do you use `py` for installation instead of `python` which you use to run your script?

Comment: yes, I did replace `<pkg>` with `pyqt5`, which is what I was trying to install, I am just trying to be generic here. 2. If by installation is completed successfully means having them showed up in the `env/Lib/site-packages` folder, and terminal giving me the output `Installed succesfully`, then yes. 3. I can run my script with either `python` or `py`, its the same. For installation, I used `py` as I am following the official documentation seen [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-packages).

Comment: Edit to my previous comment, I have to use `python` to run my script, but not `py`.
I created a new folder on my desktop, and moved the venv folder to it, and `pip freeze` is working as expected now.
Weird that `pip freeze` is not working at my original directory (where it used to work), but I can run my script without problem with `python script.py`.